# how to connect hbase with authentication using drill?

Tags: security, hadoop, authentication, hbase, apache-drill

we create a data warehouse in hadoop hbase database and there is a hadoop cluster with hbase database and a drill sql engine cluster. i want to get access each table of hbase to a user and all user can't see all database tables. how can we have security and authentication  in this platform.how can we control access to hbase table during drill? i know that hbase has authentication. but i don't know how it work with drill?
do we have to change our sql engine on hbase?
how to connect hbase with authentication using drill?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Apache Ranger? It has HBase plugin. By using Ranger you can manage policies for access to databases, tables, or even column. You can see gif demo here: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/12682/apache-ranger-and-hbase.html